# php regex replace slashes and spaces and hyphens

Tags: php, regex

I have fews combinations of strings that I need to bring in to one pattern, that is multiple spaces should be removed, double hyphens should be replaced with single hypen, and single space should be replaced with single hyphen.

I have already tried this expression.

```
$output = preg_replace( "/[^[:space:]a-z0-9]/e", "", $output );
$output = trim( $output );
$output = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '-', $output );
```

But this fails in few combinations.

I need help in making all of these combinations to work perfectly:

```
1. steel-black
2. steel- black
3. steel    black
```

I should also remove any of these as well `\r\n\t`.

Comment: can you post sample data a your desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this (thanks for the [better suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473633/php-regex-replace-slashes-and-spaces-and-hyphens/25473713#comment39754613_25473713) @Robin) :

```
$s = 'here is  a test-- with -- spaces-and hyphens';
$s = preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $s);
echo $s;
```

Replace any number of whitespace characters or hyphens with a single hyphen.
You may also want to use `trim($s, '-')` to remove any leading or trailing hyphens. It would also be possible to do this directly in the regex but I think it's clearer not to.

Output:

```
here-is-a-test-with-spaces-and-hyphens
```

If there are additional characters that you would like to remove, you can simply add them into the bracket expression, for example `/[()\s-]+/` would also remove parentheses. However, you might prefer to just replace all non-word characters:

```
$s = 'here is  a test- with -- spaces ( ), hyphens (-), newlines
    and tabs (  )';
$s = trim(preg_replace('/[\W]+/', '-', $s), '-');
echo $s;
```

This replaces any number of characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with a hyphen and removes any leading and trailing hyphens.

Output:

```
here-is-a-test-with-spaces-hyphens-newlines-and-tabs
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not directly using `preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-', $output)` ?

Comment: @Robin for some reason that didn't occur to me...I've edited my answer to use your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: what about \r\n\t ? i think in my regex [:space:] was removing these?

Comment: also i need to remove parenthesis from the string as well

Comment: @Muhammad `\s` works for those characters as well. I have added to my answer to explain about removing additional characters.

Comment: Thanks man, i didn't notice before, but i have implemented it, and its working fine now. @TomFenech

Comment: @Muhammad no problem, if your problem is solved don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the ✔

Comment: @TomFenech please i need to remove single and double qoutes from the string as well, please update the expression please :(

Comment: @Muhammad You can add quotes into the character class of the first expression, or use the second expression which already does that, as I have explained in my answer. Anyway, I already solved your original problem, so you should accept my answer.